# what does __init__ of one class do in another class body?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, singleton

```
class Borg:
    """Borg pattern making the class attributes global"""
    _shared_data = {} # Attribute dictionary

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self._shared_data # Make it an attribute dictionary

        
class Singleton(Borg): #Inherits from the Borg class
    """This class now shares all its attributes among its various instances"""
    # This essentially makes the singleton objects an object-oriented global variable

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Borg.__init__(self)  # WHAT DOES THIS DO? Why is borg initialized with the self of this class?
        self._shared_data.update(kwargs) # Update the attribute dictionary by inserting a new key-value pair 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._shared_data) # Returns the attribute dictionary for printing
```

`Borg.__init__(self)`  What does this do? What is borg initialized with the self of this class?

Comment: An instance of your `Singleton` class is an instance of `Borg`, and `Borg`'s `__init__` method is there to correctly initialise a `Borg` instance. So one way or another it is a good idea for it to be called.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an object of a derived class, Python only calls the `__init__` special method for the most derived class. If ancestor classes require initialization, it is up to the programmer of the derived class to *explicitely* call `__init__` on those classes.

What you show is the old Python 2 compatible idiom: `Borg.__init__` is the unbound initialization method of the `Borg` class. If you call it you have to pass it the object as the first parameter, because in Python if `a` is an object from a `A` class having a `m` method with no parameters, `a.m()` is the same as `A.m(a)` - if there are parameters, they will just come after the object.

In this case and assuming Python 3, the most idiomatic way would be:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()  # exactly the same as Borg.__init__(self)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the "child **init**" will be executet.

So in your case if you call Singleton, only the Singleton **init** will be executet.

Answer (score 0):

creating an instance of the `Singleton` class like this `mySingleton = Singleton(someArgs)` will call the constructor `def __init__(self, **kwargs):`initializing the new instance of your class. the first thing that is being initialized by the initializeation code block is to call the initialization of the underlying class `Borg` by calling `Borg.__init__(self)`, this happens in pretty much all languages granted sometimes in a slightly different layout, but it has to happen in order to pass in any required arguments to the underlying base class